# Old Google Spreadsheet urls became invalid, how to retrieve new urls?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

We have a huge collection of spreadsheets with statistical data. There is one "master-sheet" with links to all other sheets. Most of these links have been there for a long time. It seems Google has changed link-formats over time, including id's used to identify the sheets.

Old link format, used often in our master sheet:
http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=rcTO3doih5lvJCjgLSvlajA

Newer link format, used occasionally in our master sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkBd6lyS3EmpdDlSTTVWUkU3Z254aEhERmVuQWZaeWc

Newest link format, where Google redirects when you visit a link in the "newer" format:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WipPWXQqXSjj9vPTu1LXD8IxeTfIn4RIBrGaOBd0DXc/pub

Now recently (since a week or so) Google seems to have quit support for the first format. I.e., most of our links are dead, so we can't access our spreadsheets. And we have no way to find out what the new, working, links are.

Does anyone know how to retrieve the spreadsheets when all you have is the old link? We don't have a Google Drive folder with the spreadsheets, so that solution doesn't work.

Thank you so much for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the ID of the old link and put it in place of the ID of the newer link (not the newest!), then it will work.

e.g. old link:

http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=rcTO3doih5lvJCjgLSvlajA

Take `rcTO3doih5lvJCjgLSvlajA` and insert below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=

Results in: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=rcTO3doih5lvJCjgLSvlajA

You can then follow the redirect to get the newest version of the link